# How to customize directory permission for users from FTP

Tags: linux, ftp, file-permissions, vsftpd

I have a directory like this

```
home
+-- dirA
+-- dirB
|   +-- fileA
|   +-- fileB
```

and multiple users and groups.

`groupA` has `user1`, `user2`, `groupB` has `user3`

I have set up permissions like these:

```
chown user3 /home
setfacl -R -m g:groupA:wr home/dirB
chmod -d /home/dirB user1
```

`user1` and `user3` are in sudo list.

Now when I try to log in through `SSH` for `user1`, I always get error like `Could not chdir to home directory /home/dirB: Permission denied`. When I log in through `FTP` with `user2`, I get `500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/dirB`.

However, when I use `user3` to log in, which is the owner of `home`, it works find.

I am running `vsftpd` on the server. The system is `ubuntu 14.04`.